# Including string search in multiple choice questions in ODK Collect

Tags: android, odk, odk-xform

The question is based on using the ODK Collect on an Android platform:

I am working with multiple choice questions type where the choices are being sourced from a .csv file. Thus far it is a standard ODK procedure, however, I want to **include a string search option in the question** due to the large number of options in the .csv. The string search is to **reduce the number of choices** the participant has to go through, and hence the search needs to be performed multiple times.
**What is the best way to go about this?**

My thoughts so far: Work with the ODK Collect source code to "inject" a string search option into the respective activity windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the search function in the "appearance column", and example is given below

```
search('locationset','matches','countryid',1)
```

where locationset is the name of csv file, and countryid is a column in the csv, 1 is the value that i want it to search
I've attached an image of a form, to have a better idea. Hope this helps

[image]